# Regex Returning True and False

Tags: javascript, regex

```
 windowLocation = /(^\/t\d+)|(^\/post\?.+(post|reply){1})|(\/privmsg\?.+(post|reply){1})/g;
 windowLocation.test(window.location.pathname+window.location.search);
```

This code keeps return `true` then if you try it again it returns `false`. I need to test pathnames and searches that are like so

```
 /t12
 /post?t=2&mode=reply
 /privmsg?mode=reply&p=62
```

Any suggestions as to why this keeps returning both true and false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to use of `/g` (global) flag in your regex. If you remove it will be fine.

```
windowLocation = /(^\/t\d+)|(^\/post\?.+(post|reply){1})|(\/privmsg\?.+(post|reply){1})/;
```

When you use the global flag in the regex, the `lastIndex` property is maintained between different calls `RegExp#test(string)`. The `lastIndex` property is the index at which to start the next match.

With above regex I get:

```
windowLocation.test("/t12");
true
windowLocation.test("/t12");
true
windowLocation.test("/t12");
true
```

#### Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Oh ok so by making it global flag it was returning back and forth? I sort of get it but hey either way thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes use of `g` maintains internal state of lastIndex and causes problems. You don't really need global flag for your need anyway.

Comment: Yeah I was waiting on the time limit thing to go away. my bad